# Forbidden access

Tags: visual-studio, web-config, hosting

Just got my first website public "YES"... But, when i try to access it it says

```
    Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

But if i add `/Views/Index.html` to the URL, it works fine and displays my website, but without it, it dosent? The website is coded in visual studio, and i have tried adding to my web.config, but without any luck.

```
    <system.webServer>
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
<files>
<add value="vViews/index.html" />
</files>
</defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Any suggestions on what can fix it so i can see my website at www.mywebsite.dk instad of www.mywebsite.dk/Views/Index.html

Thanks

Comment: You have **v**Views instead of views in the `value`.

Comment: Just saw that! Tried Added it to my code, where it was <add value="Views/Index.html" /> But didn't change anything.

Comment: Do you have any rewrites in your web.config? You would normally have a rewrite that serves your view unless the physical path exists (css or js files etc). I don't think default document is what your looking for.